# making scrollbar always visible

Tags: css

In my website I want that the scrollbar on the rightside is always visible if it is needed or not.

Comment: would this be on the browser? or in an element in your page (e.g. a div)

Answer (score 7):

try:     `body { overflow-y:scroll }`

Comment: not sure if overflow-y is supported by ie8. I know that the overflow property definitly is. Just a small heads up there.

Comment: @ZeSimon according sitepoint reference they are `fully supported in Internet Explorer versions 7 & 8. Safari 3+, Chrome 2+, Firefox 2+ and Opera 9.5+ all support these properties.`

Comment: @ZeSimon Luckily, we have the [comparison tables at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)). According to those, the overflow-y property has some issues in IE browsers, but it says nothing about overflow-y:scroll not working.

Comment: Well in that case all is well then. Sorry I just wanted to give some heads up because I remembered having a similar problem sometime ago.